# Should I be using Sympy to first develop an equation or go straight through Numpy?

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I noticed that instead of using Numpy to change my data step by step I could develop an end equation with Sympy, simplify it, and then lambdify it, such that I have the end point of a Numpy program.

I'd like to know if such an approach is not a waste of time.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: Your time or computational time?  `lambdify` is basically a semantic translator.  It doesn't have deep knowldge of what works best in numpy.  Look at other SO that use `lambdify` to better see its limits.

Comment: @hpaulj Computational time. And what do you mean by SO?

Comment: SO, StackOverflow - this forum!  We can't say without seeing some examples whether this 2 step approach is more efficient.  It will depend on thr equations, and the size of the arrays applied to them.  `sympy` isn't known for its speed.  Make sure you look at the generated python function code.